# Extension of Schwarz lemma in Serge Lang's Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

An extension of the Schwarz lemma states that:

> If $f:D\to D$ is an analytic function of the unit disc to itself such
>   that $f(0)=0$. Then $|f'(0)|=a_1\leq 1$ anf if $|a_1|=1$ then
>   $f(z)=a_1z$ where $f(z)=a_1z+$ higher terms

I am stuck with it's proof in the last part.[image] The book proceeds with a proof using the method of contradiction. How does the proof directly conclude at last by the contradiction? No explanation is provided. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose what he means is to invoke the triangle inequality:

$$\left |  \frac{f\left ( tz \right )}{tz}\right | = \left | a_1(1+t^{m-1})+h \right | \geq 1+ t^{m-1}-\left | h \right | \geq 1+ t^{m-1}-C t^m,$$

since $\left |  a_1\right | = 1$. Note $C$ is positive. For $t$ small enough, say, $t < 1/C$, the above right-hand side is strictly greater than $1$, which is the desired result.

Personally, I do not appreciate this proof. The one that I learned (which is much easier to generalize) goes:

> For $f(z) = a_1 z+ a_2 z^2 + \cdots, $ consider $g(z):= f(z)/z$. Evidently $g$ is holomorphic in $D$. Along every circle of radius $r<1$ centered at $0$, we have:
>   $$\left | g(z) \right | = \left | \frac{f(z)}{z} \right | \leq \frac{1}{\left | z \right |} = \frac{1}{r}.$$
>   Apply the max. mod. principle, for all $\left | z \right |<r$, $\left | g(z) \right |\leq \frac{1}{r}$. Now: 1) letting $r \rightarrow 1^-$, we get $\left | g(z) \right | \leq 1$ which implies $\left | f(z) \right |< \left | z \right |$; 2) based on 1), letting $z \rightarrow 0$, $\left | g(0) \right | = \left | f'(0) \right | \leq 1$. $\square$

Another useful yet equivalent theorem is Schwarz-Pick Lemma. You may as well look at that one.